# Compilation error when extending class and defining a method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, page-factory

I am getting compilation error when I am extending Loginpage class through Loginbusiness, define a method but compilation throws an error to remove illegal identifiers(eg. public) and also for arguments passed to that methods:

**Login Page:**

```
package com.pages.page;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.utility.PageUtility;

public class LoginPage {

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.SIGNIN_USERNAME_ID)
    @CacheLookup
    public WebElement userNameTextField;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.SIGNIN_PASSWORD_ID)
    @CacheLookup
    public WebElement passwordTextField;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = PageUtility.SIGNIN_SUBMIT_ID)
    @CacheLookup
    public WebElement signInButton;
}
```

**LoginBusiness:**

```
package com.business;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.driver.Driver;
import com.page.LoginPage;



public class LoginBusiness extends LoginPage {
    public LoginPage loginpage;

    public LoginBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    //  loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(), LoginPage.class);


     WebElement loginToApplication(String username String password) {

            userNameTextField.clear();
            userNameTextField.sendKeys("aaaa");
            passwordTextField.clear();
            passwordTextField.sendKeys("4444");
            signInButton.click();

    }

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there is a couple of things wrong in there:

1. Do you really need `LoginBusiness` class? Seems like it all could be done in `LoginPage`.
2. If you don't use the `WebElements` anywhere outside the `LoginBusiness` class they can be `protected` instead of `public`.
3. remove the line with `public LoginPage loginpage;`, you already extended the class, this is probably causing the compilation issue.
4. Inside `LoginBusiness` class define a private variable `private WebDriver driver;` and set it inside the constructor `this.driver = driver;`
5. Your `loginToApplication` function is of type `WebElement` while it does not return any `WebElements`. Instead make it `public void` and don't return anything. **Or** make it return the page that you land on after login (and its type not void).

Half of those errors were probably pointed out to you by the compiler...

Adding the refactored `LoginBusiness` class here:

```
public class LoginBusiness extends LoginPage {

public LoginBusiness(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

//  loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(), LoginPage.class);

public void loginToApplication(String username, String password) {
    userNameTextField.clear();
    userNameTextField.sendKeys("aaaa");
    passwordTextField.clear();
    passwordTextField.sendKeys("4444");
    signInButton.click();
}
```

}

Comment: As per the architecture we have to define methods of every page in the loginbusiness class, and I have return public void but it throws compilation error

Comment: Post the log please, code alone is not enough.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
  expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; 
  expected-- showing this kind of messages

Comment: I have edited my answer with the fixed `LoginBusiness` class, this should help you proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help its working now

Comment: If I helped you solve the problem please remember to tick the answer.

Comment: Agree with point 1 here. That "Business" architecture seems very odd.  It's like a workflow/helper that just handles things the LoginPage can do on its own.